# Sum numbers in one cell that contains line break - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum

Image of Gift List Here

[image: 1]

I'm looking to enter the SUM of the listed values in D4 to C4.

However, I used a line break between the list of numbers in D4. I found a [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tvzy.png) from 5 years ago with various SUM methods, but they must all be specific to Excel and not to Google Sheets.

Any ideas?

I tried using the following functions:

=SumAlt(D4)

=SumLines(D4)

I included 0s in the blank spaces and still no luck. It reads as an error and unknown function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
 =sum(split(D4,char(10)))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: you may need to convert the result of split to numbers. `=arrayformula(sum(--split(D4,char(10))))`